# Copy with base point (like Autocad)

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible to copy an object on a base point and than paste it like it happens in autocad (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and then paste it somewhere else in the scene?

Comment: you can duplicate with shift D or alt D (link-duplication), then put the 3D cursor wherever you want in the scene, then select your copy, shift S > Selected to 3D Cursor

Comment: Thank you. I used something like that, but I was wondering if there was something more intuitive and less cumbersome.

Comment: maybe an addon allows to do it, or maybe it needs to be created, you would like to have a shortcut for Paste To 3D Cursor?

Comment: maybe it could be a useful option

Comment: all suggestions to developers here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: done it thanks!